# How to prevent my ASP.NET app from processing same request from an email hyperlink a second time?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, http, url

Here's the problem...

1. My backend software sends user an email with a hyperlink that contains data (ie. "?dataName=dataYadaYada").
2. User receives email and clicks hyperlink
3. My ASP.NET app gets the request, processes data in queryString, and sends back response page with "THANK YOU" plus links to other pages.
4. PROBLEM:  If user re-posts the page or clicks one of the page links, my ASP.NET gets same request again with same queryString, and mistakenly processes it.

How can my ASP.NET app recognize and skip a request that it has already processed?

The only solution I can think of is backend putting unique sequential number into the email hyperlink, and then ASP.NET storing this into session variable for detection of 2nd request of same queryString.

Is there better way?

Comment: Don't set the dataName in your follow-up mail links. On server you will then know this is not an first email click.

For repost, you could set something in the Session on server so you know user has been sent an email already

Comment: What do you mean by 'dataname'?  I cannot find in Microsoft docs.  I'm not using SQL

Comment: You named the querystring variable in your question dataName

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple - when you receive the request, record in your database that the dataname has been used, and check for it every time you receive a request.

If the dataname on its own is not unique enough then yeah append another parameter containing something which (in combination with the dataname if that makes sense) allows you to identify the specific email from which it originated.

P.S. using session is no good because it's temporary and lost when the browser closes. If the user clicks the email again in a new browser session it won't detect it. You need permanent storage like a database

Comment: What do you mean by 'dataname'?  I cannot find in Microsoft docs.  I'm not using SQL.

Comment: @DougNull dataname as in the URL parameter which you yourself described in the question, i.e. `dataName=dataYadaYada`. It's not some special property. I was just using your own example to illustrate the answer. P.S. If you are not using a database at all then you are going to have a problem because you have no way to store any information and remember whether the same link has been visited before - which was the whole point of your question, I think.